# custom query wordpress for search without drafts

Tags: sql, wordpress

I created a custom query for searching posts in Wordpress. It looks like this:

`SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE '%$keywords%' OR post_title LIKE '%$keywords%' AND post_status = 'publish' AND (post_type = 'post' OR post_type = 'column')"`

`$keywords` is set by a GET of a form like this `$keywords = str_replace(" ", "+", $_GET['s']);`

It also shows all drafts of a post. What do I have to change in this query to stop it from showing drafts?

I know there is a standard search in Wordpress, but I can't use this one because I'm running Wordpress on MSSQL.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: well, if there is a solution with query_posts(), that's also fine with me. I would like to search through all titles and content (and preferably authors) of all post_types

Comment: Can you add a bit of the code surrounding the query? Where do you replace the `$keywords` value?

Comment: Shure, I editted the original message ^^

Comment: In the OR between the LIKEs, I think you might need to wrap both LIKEs with brackets. I'm not familiar with MSSQL but Maybe as the first LIKE resolves to true the rest isn't considered, breaking the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit: I tested MSSQL a bit and it seems that the missing brackets are the problem. I think this query should work.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE (post_content LIKE '%$keywords%' OR post_title LIKE '%$keywords%') AND post_status = 'publish' AND (post_type = 'post' OR post_type = 'column')"
```

$keyword is the var you get from the POST

```
$args = array('s' => $keyword, 'post_type' => array('post', 'column') );

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

You can pass other parameters as well, you can check them [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Also, avoid using `query_posts`, you can read why in the first paragraph [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried this, but it doesn't work. Maybe because I use MSSQL?

Comment: By the way; when I replace 's' for 'tag' is does work, but only for tags and not for titles and content

Comment: @jeroen, well, in that case, I don't know, maybe this can help (https://github.com/ProjectNami/projectnami)

Comment: thanks, I checked that one out earlier, but with no result. I think I'll stick to my custom query since it actually searches, but still have to find out how to exclude drafts. thanks for your input!